# How to Pull Stackoverflow Available job using it's API

Tags: api

Refer to the stackoverflow API
https://api.stackexchange.com/

Can i pull the available jobs as per highlighted picture below as json or text

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's no API endpoint for that, but if you're willing to put up with good old XML, there's an RSS feed.

Note the "Subscribe to RSS" link at the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/jobs.

The feed accepts the same parameters as the search page itself. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/feed?q=javascript&l=Seattle%2c+WA%2c+USA&u=Miles&d=20

Comment: This has been deprecated sometime in the last year.